# Table with custom borders

Tags: html, xhtml, html-table, border

I'm trying to make a table similar to the following:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<table bordercolor="#000000">
    <tr>
        <th width="200" style="border-right: 2px dashed; border-bottom: 2px dashed;">
            Player1 Status
        </th>
        <th  width="200" style="border-right: 2px dashed; border-bottom: 2px dashed;">
            Player2 Status
        </th>
        <th  width="200" style="border-right: 2px dashed; border-bottom: 2px dashed;">
            Player3 Status
        </th>
        <th  width="200" style="border-bottom: 2px dashed;">
            Player4 Status
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="200" style="border-right: 2px dashed;">Your Trun!</td>
        <td width="200" style="border-right: 2px dashed;">Not Your Turn!</td>
        <td width="200" style="border-right: 2px dashed;">Not Your Turn!</td>
        <td width="200">Not Your Turn!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="200" style="border-right: 2px dashed;">Remaining Moves: 5</td>
        <td width="200" style="border-right: 2px dashed;">Remaining Moves: 5</td>
        <td width="200" style="border-right: 2px dashed;">Remaining Moves: 5</td>
        <td width="200">Remaining Moves: 5</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But I have faced a problem when removing `Your Trun!` statement, the table will be like this:

[image]

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: You may want to look at using css classes for this to make it a little easier to change should you want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `&nbsp;`:

```
<table bordercolor="#000000">
    <tr>
        <th width="200" style="border-right: 2px dashed; border-bottom: 2px dashed;">
            Player1 Status
        </th>
        <th  width="200" style="border-right: 2px dashed; border-bottom: 2px dashed;">
            Player2 Status
        </th>
        <th  width="200" style="border-right: 2px dashed; border-bottom: 2px dashed;">
            Player3 Status
        </th>
        <th  width="200" style="border-bottom: 2px dashed;">
            Player4 Status
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="200" style="border-right: 2px dashed;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="200" style="border-right: 2px dashed;">Not Your Turn!</td>
        <td width="200" style="border-right: 2px dashed;">Not Your Turn!</td>
        <td width="200">Not Your Turn!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="200" style="border-right: 2px dashed;">Remaining Moves: 5</td>
        <td width="200" style="border-right: 2px dashed;">Remaining Moves: 5</td>
        <td width="200" style="border-right: 2px dashed;">Remaining Moves: 5</td>
        <td width="200">Remaining Moves: 5</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Vgk2W/

Comment: The reason for this is that some browsers treat an empty table cell as if it weren't there and so don't draw its borders. Putting the html space entity in forces it to draw the table properly.

Answer (score 2):

css property "empty-cells:show;" may also work in more modern browsers
  test: http://jsfiddle.net/Vgk2W/1/
  support: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/tables.html